# Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController on UIViewController which is already presenting

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native

I have a module on react native and throw the error in the title of this ask. Here is the code of the module, I don't know swift or objective-c, so I need you explain me like "swift for idiots"

```
#import "CheckoutMercadoPagoModule.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@import MercadoPagoSDK;

@implementation CheckoutMercadoPagoModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startCheckout:(NSString *)publicKey:(NSString *)prefId:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {

    [MercadoPagoContext setPublicKey: publicKey];
    [MercadoPagoContext setSiteID:@"MLA"];

    UINavigationController *checkoutFlow = [MPFlowBuilder startCheckoutViewController:prefId callback:^(Payment *payment) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"id": payment._id, @"status": payment.status};
        resolve(dictionary);
    } callbackCancel:nil];

    AppDelegate *share = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) share.window.rootViewController;
    [nav presentViewController:checkoutFlow animated:YES completion:^{}];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is code that React generated?

Comment: no, this is the code written by some guy who make the bridge between MercadoPago SDK and React Native

Comment: yes but this don't solve my problem, thx

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting on Window itself instead of rootviewcontroller

```
  [share.window presentViewController:checkoutFlow animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

}

Comment: can you write an example for me plz, i don't know swift and I have the meeting in few hours

Comment: The code you posted is Objective-C, you still want the and in swift?

Comment: no, sorry, I think was swift, I just want make it work T.T

Comment: CheckoutMercadoPagoModule.m:28:12: Property 'keywindow' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'; did you mean 'window'?

Comment: Change it to window and try

Comment: when I change it to window

Comment: Sorry to say you're probably not getting closer to a solution this way.  The problem is that code is in a race condition with some other VC presentation.  It's not solvable without first understanding where/when `startCheckout` is being called.  Almost certainly, it's being called while another VC (probably the root nav itself) is being presented.

Comment: CheckoutMercadoPagoModule.m:28:19: No visible @interface for 'UIWindow' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'